# Flat Rate Time: 1989 Chevy S10 4x4 4.3. R&R the engine w/long block

Tags: engine, chevrolet, s10, book-hours

Former ASE master retired since 2003. Haven't wrenched on a major project like this in years. Would like to help out a good friend who has 1989 Chevy S10 4x4 4.3-liter v6. The vehicles body frame and drive train are in good shape, but the engine is blown. Found a Mitchell rebuilt long block that has been sitting in the machine shop of a local auto parts store for several years w/matching vin and was able to purchase it for a song... I need to get some type of idea on the flat rate for R&Ring the engine and long block before I get in over my head. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While your question is absolutely on topic for the site, I've not seen many of them like this answered in quite some time. Hopefully someone might have the information, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: Thank you, was hoping someone might be able to at least ballpark it

Comment: I feel your pain ... just started a new project with my son to do an S10 LS engine swap ... I say "with", but I'll end up doing 85% of the work, lol.

Answer (score 1):

R&R flat rate time is 13.1 hours. With AC add .4 hours. With power steering add .5 hours. With automatic transmission add .2 hours.  Source is Repair-Source.

Comment: Nicely done! If you have access, there are several more older questions of this sort hanging out there. Appreciate you adding in the detail! +1

Comment: Thank you @Paulster2. I will take a look. Do you have a recommendation for the search criteria?

Comment: Under the "Tags" tab (left hand nav), select "book-hours" and go from there. Or just follow the [tag:book-hours] link.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!